# React.js: How to filter JSX element array on custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting with a simple array of JSX elements:

```
const jsxArray = dataItems.map(item => (
  <div>
    <Header>{item.title}</Header>
    <Paragraph>{item.body}</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph customAttribute={item.isActive} >{item.tags}</Paragraph>    
  </div>
))
```

Inside render, or rather return since I use functional components for everything now, I'd like to filter for JSX elements where the `isActive` attribute was tagged `true`.

```
return (
  {jsxArray
    .filter(jsxElement => // want to filter in JSX elements 
      // that are true for customAttribute keyed to `item.isActive`)
  }
)
```

Is there any way to do it?

If there is not precisely a good way I am open to workarounds.

It is possible for me to simply filter the array at an earlier step. It would result in some extra code duplication though, since I would still need the array of unfiltered JSX elements elsewhere.

Comment: *"It is possible for me to simply filter the array at an earlier step"*. That is what you should do. *"It would result in some extra code duplication though"*. You should probably extract a component that renders that markup.

Answer (score 7):

You don't filter the list after you render it. At that point it's just a tree of nodes that doesn't have much meaning anymore.

Instead you filter the items *first*, and *then render* only the items that pass your criteria.

```
const jsxArray = dataItems.filter(item => item.isActive).map(item => (
  <div>
    <h3>{item.title}</p>
    <p>{item.body}</p>
    <p customAttribute={item.isActive} >{item.tags}</p>    
  </div>
))
```

---

> It is possible for me to simply filter the array at an earlier step. It would result in some extra code duplication though, since I would still need the array of unfiltered JSX elements elsewhere.

Not necessarily. When dealing with filtering like this myself I create two variables, one for the raw unfiltered list and one for the filtered items. Then whatever you're rendering can choose one or the other depending on its needs.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const filteredItems = items.filter(item => item.isActive)

return <>
  <p>Total Items: ${items.length}</p>
  <ItemList items={filteredItems} />
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would filter the plain data first and then render only the markup for the filtered elements as described in @Alex Wayne answer.

If you worry about duplication of the markup, that can be solved by extracting a component from it:

```
const Item = ({title, body, isActive, tags}) => (
    <div>
        <Header>{title}</Header>
        <Paragraph>{body}</Paragraph>
        <Paragraph customAttribute={isActive}>{tags}</Paragraph>    
    </div>
);
```

For rendering the filtered list you can then do:

```
{items.filter(item => item.isActive).map(item => <Item {...item} />)}
```

and for the unfiltered list:

```
{items.map(item => <Item {...item} />)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing the `jsx` element properties (which I think it's either not possible or very difficult) I suggest you to act in this way:

1. Save the renderer function for items in an arrow function

   ```
   const itemRenderer = item => (
       <div>
           <Header>{item.title}</Header>
           <Paragraph>{item.body}</Paragraph>
           <Paragraph customAttribute={item.isActive} >{item.tags}</Paragraph>    
       </div>
   )
   ```
2. Save the filter function in an arrow function

   ```
   const activeItems = item => item.isActive
   ```
3. Use them to filter and map

   ```
   const jsxArray = dataItems.filter(activeItems).map(itemRenderer)
   ```
4. Use them to map only

   ```
   const jsxArray = dataItems.filter(activeItems).map(itemRenderer)
   ```

Hope this helps!